# select all data before a specify service ID

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Good morning !

I have create this fiddle for you:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=4e2bdf9aecca8b69d829770589c14807

Explanation:

1. Create a table "timeslots"
2. Fill this table with a date range from tomorrow to + 2 days , time range. 14-18 o'clock.
3. Update 3 times lots and set service to "2" (I chose random IDs)
4. `SELECT * FROM timeslots ORDER BY timeslot ASC`

And this is the result, which shows the fiddle.
But now I need to expand my sql query to get a specific result and I don't know how I can realize it. Maybe you have some idea.

First step:
I would like to get only the timeslots where service = 0:

Easy for me:

```
SELECT * FROM timeslots WHERE service = 0
```

A part of the result:

```
2021-07-06 14:00:00 0
2021-07-06 15:00:00 0
2021-07-06 16:00:00 2 (not this value, because service is not 0)
2021-07-06 17:00:00 0
```

All ok !

But If there exist - on the same day - a timeslot with service 2 (like the result above 2021-07-06 16:00:00) I need only the values AFTER 2021-07-06 16:00:00. In this example the result should be:

```
2021-07-06 17:00:00
```

I hope you understand my problem and you can help me !
Thank you !

Comment: [Homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `NOT EXISTS`, because you want to look at rows where *not exists* a service-two slot on the same day at that time or later.

```
select *
from timeslots ts
where not exists
(
  select null
  from timeslots ts2
  where date(ts2.timeslot) = date(ts.timeslot)
  and time(ts2.timeslot) >= time(ts2.timeslot)
  and service = 2
)
order by timeslot;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=6cf862d80445fcda030e2be35adb4909